# IFormFile is not working with Azure function Open API

Tags: azure-functions, openapi

I want to create an endpoint that should allow multiple files to upload like this

[image]

However IFormFile is not working with Azure function open API, I also tried using byte[] is allows uploading a single file only and List<byte[]> is not even showing the browse file option

I tried using byte[], List<byte[]> and IFromFile none working for me